# Was my edit removing noise and a link wrong?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The following suggested edit by myself:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12934797

In my opinion removed the noise at the end of the answer and removed a link to a personal git. It was initially rejected by a reviewer before the OP.

The reason I am asking is because a reviewer rejected my edit initially, not why the OP did.

Was I right in my edit?

Note: having looked again I could have made a couple of grammar improvements but not much more.

Comment: Looks like the OP themselves rejected your edit. They are allowed to do so single handedl.

Comment: It's also a pretty bad answer; it's just a code dump with nothing else...

Comment: I'm also not sure if the link should go; it's a link to an article about the same topic as the question (looks like the author wrote the article on GIT while writing his answer on SO).  Not sure that it's needed, but also don't think it's wrong for it to be there, although he really ought to explain the link, rather than just including it with no context.

Comment: I've commented on the answer and mentioned that it is being discussed here on meta. Hopefully he'll come here and read the comments.

Comment: Your edit was valid.  His rejection was somewhat valid, but less valid than the edit, as that kind of noise is generally discouraged (more so by some than others).  Yay, gray area.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: This is addressed in the third paragraph.

Comment: @NisseEngström Ah OK, missed that detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your edit was rejected because you removed the link, which is also mentioned by [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327540/was-my-edit-removing-noise-and-a-link-wrong#comment364807_327540). The link doesn't really add value but most reviewers in that queue don't take the time to review that thoroughly.

The answer could do without the noise so you spotted that correctly. On the other hand there wasn't an awful lot of content, except the code blob, to improve.

Maybe if you elaborated in the comment that the link was only a copy of the content and doesn't have any added background value to the post, careful reviewers might have spotted that and approved in that case. That a link points to a personal git by itself is not a reason to be removed.

The rejection of the OP, however, was binding in this case for the definitive rejection of your attempt to improve their post.

A gray area indeed, as noted by [Will](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327540/was-my-edit-removing-noise-and-a-link-wrong#comment364828_327540)